# Python, Split the input string on elements of other list and remove digits from it

Tags: python, list

I have had some trouble with this problem, and I need your help.
I have to make a Python method (mySplit(x)) which takes an input list (which only has one string as element), split that element on the elements of other list and digits.
I use Python 3.6
So here is an example:

```
l=['I am learning']
l1=['____-----This4ex5ample---aint___ea5sy;782']
banned=['-', '+' , ',', '#', '.', '!', '?', ':', '_', ' ', ';']
```

The returned lists should be like this:

```
mySplit(l)=['I', 'am', 'learning']
mySplit(l1)=['This', 'ex', 'ample', 'aint', 'ea', 'sy']
```

I have tried the following, but I always get stuck:

```
def mySplit(x):

    l=['-', '+' , ',', '#', '.', '!', '?', ':', '_', ';'] #Banned chars
    l2=[i for i in x if i not in l] #Removing chars from input list
    l2=",".join(l2)
    l3=[i for i in l2 if not i.isdigit()] #Removes all the digits
    l4=[i for i in l3 if i is not ',']
    l5=[",".join(l4)]
    l6=l5[0].split(' ')
    return l6
```

and

```
mySplit(l1)
mySplit(l)
```

returns:

```
['T,h,i,s,e,x,a,m,p,l,e,a,i,n,t,e,a,s,y']
['I,', ',a,m,', ',l,e,a,r,n,i,n,g']
```

Comment: Why not just: `re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', l1[0])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use re.split() for this task:

```
import re
w_list = [i for i in re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z]', 
          '____-----This4ex5ample---aint___ea5sy;782') if i ]

Out[12]: ['This', 'ex', 'ample', 'aint', 'ea', 'sy']
```

Comment: I have used your suggestion and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would import the `punctuation` marks from `string` and proceed with regular expressions as follows.

```
l=['I am learning']
l1=['____-----This4ex5ample---aint___ea5sy;782']
import re
from string import punctuation
punctuation # to see the punctuation marks.

>>> '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

' '.join([re.sub('[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\d]',' ', w) for w in l]).split()
```

Here is the output:

```
>>>   ['I', 'am', 'learning']
```

Notice the `\d` attached at the end of the punctuation marks to remove any digits.

Similarly,

```
' '.join([re.sub('[!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\d]',' ', w) for w in l1]).split()
```

Yields

```
>>> ['This', 'ex', 'ample', 'aint', 'ea', 'sy']
```

You can also modify your function as follows:

```
def mySplit(x):

    banned = ['-', '+' , ',', '#', '.', '!', '?', ':', '_', ';'] + list('0123456789')#Banned chars
    return ''.join([word if not word in banned else ' ' for word in list(x[0]) ]).split()
```